# RSS feed for new YouTube channels not associated with users

Tags: youtube, rss

In the past I've subscribed using RSS to a lot of favorite YouTube channels. For example, channels following this format all have RSS feed information attached to them:
http://www.youtube.com/user/hickok45/

However, more recently, I've been finding some channels with a different URL format, and those don't seem to have RSS information associated with them. For example, https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdoRMzGcCBpjKTClFHGI-Yg

Does anyone know if there is any way to either convert the new format to the old format (I've tried a few things but none worked), or to get an RSS feed for all uploads for the new channel format?

Answer (score 1):

The RSS feed is located at https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC...